# Prevent Office365 mail exchange from being an open relay

Tags: email, exchange, office365, relay

I wish to use Office365 as a mail exchange for my server. It will have a single account - support@example.com and I will log in to the Office365 website to see all emails sent to this email address. I will send emails from the Office365 website and also relay emails from a php-cli script using [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) via the Office365 server.

I have added the account for support@example.com and I am able to send and receive emails via the Office365 website. I have also configured phpmailer with the following settings:

```
$From = "support@example.com";
$Sender = "support@example.com";
$Mailer = "sendmail";
$Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$SMTPAuth = true; //probably not needed
$Username = "support@example.com";
$Password = "xyz"; //probably not needed
```

In Office365 `Exchange Admin Centre > mail flow > connectors` I configured a connector to only allow connections from the IP address of my server.

Now when I run my test script from my server I am able to relay emails - so far so good. However when I run my test script from another server I am also able to relay emails! It seems my Office365 account is acting as an open relay! How can I prevent this from happening and only allow connections from the IP address of my server?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @DavidPostill hmm ok, sorry I didn't realize questions specific to corporate IT support were not permitted.